# Is there a better way to retrieve variables from class method

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently my code works but I wanted to know if I'm going about this the right way. I want to be able to individually call variables from method 'data_by_name' in 'otherfile.py' . At the moment I import 'otherfile.py' and put the elements into a list within 'main.py' and use tuple unpacking to give each element a variable name.

Could I go about this a better way?

otherfile.py

```
import requests
import json

API_KEY = "XXX"
PROJECT_TOKEN = "XXX"
RUN_TOKEN = "XXX"

class Data:
    def __init__(self, api_key, project_token):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.project_token = project_token
        self.params = {"api_key":api_key}
        self.get_data()

    def get_data(self):
        r = requests.get('https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/projects/PROJECT_TOKEN/last_ready_run/data', params={"api_key": API_KEY})
        self.data = json.loads(r.text)


    def data_by_name(self,country):

        data = self.data['country']
        for content in data:
            if content['Cname'].lower() == country.lower():
                print(content)
                name = content['Cname']
                pop = content['population']
                popRank = content['popRank']
                growth = content['growthRate']
                per = content['worldPer']
                area = content['area']
                capital = content['capital']
                region = content['region']
                gpd = content['gpd']
        return(name,pop,popRank,growth,per,area,capital,region,gpd)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = Data(API_KEY,PROJECT_TOKEN)
    data.data_by_name('Russia')
```

main.py

```
from ParsehubCode import Data,API_KEY,PROJECT_TOKEN

country = Data(API_KEY,PROJECT_TOKEN)
test = country.data_by_name("china")
list1 = []
for element in test:
    list1.append(element)
for x in list1:
    A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I = list1
print(A,B,C)
```

country.json

```
{
 "country": [
  {
   "Cname": "China",
   "name": "China Population 2020 (Live)",
   "population": "1,438,719,354",
   "popRank": "1",
   "growthRate": "0.39%",
   "worldPer": "18.47%",
   "area": "9,706,961 km²",
   "capital": "Beijing",
   "region": "Asia",
   "gpd": "$10,746.78"
  }
{
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
list1 = []
for element in test:
    list1.append(element)
for x in list1:
    A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I = list1
```

you could simply write

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I = test
```

---

Regardless, here's a slightly different approach.

Assuming that the input `json` structure is `{ 'country': [{ }, ..., { }] }`, 
I'd slightly modify `self.data`:

```
 self.data = {country['Cname'].lower(): country
              for country in json.loads(r.text)['country']}
```

then access this dictionary whenever required. Possibly by overwriting `__getitem__`:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.data[key.lower()]
```

Then you can access the inner dictionary using `[ ]`:

```
GlobalDataLoader(API_KEY,PROJECT_TOKEN)['china']
GlobalDataLoader(API_KEY,PROJECT_TOKEN)['china']['population']
```

Here I've renamed the `Data` class: I don't expect the constructor of a class named `Data` to access the internet, and the data seems to be global.
Still, I'd remove the `self.get_data()` call from `__init__`.

On the other hand, if you are not planning to reuse the `(API_KEY, PROJECT_TOKEN)` for a specific `GlobalDataLoader` instance, then I wouldn't store these in the instances. Instead do something like

```
data = GlobalDataLoader(project_secrets)
```

where

```
class GlobalDataLoader:    
    def __init__(self, project_secrets):
        self.load_data(project_secrets)

    def load_data(self, project_secrets):
        url = f"https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/projects/{project_secrets['project_token']}/last_ready_run/data"
        r = requests.get(url, params={"api_key": project_secrets['api_key']})
        self.data = {country['Cname'].lower(): country
                     for country in json.loads(r.text)['country']}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[key.lower()]
```

---

That being said, don't hard-code secrets into the source code.

```
API_KEY = "XXX"
PROJECT_TOKEN = "XXX"
RUN_TOKEN = "XXX"
```

You don't want this as a habit when you start using version control systems. Store these in a separate file. If you *have to* store that in a VCS, then encrypt it (e.g. use `gitcrypt`).

To reuse the idea of a wrapped dictionary, you could write a

```
class ProjectSecretsLoader:
    def __init__(self, config_file_path):
        self.load_config(config_file_path)

    def load_config(self, config_file_path):
        self.config_data = dict() # TODO

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.config_data[key]
```

then do

```
config_file_path = "..."
project_secrets = ProjectSecretsLoader(config_file_path)
data = GlobalDataLoader(project_secrets)
```

---

Last, but not least `requests.get` might fail, `json.loads` might fail. The result of `json.loads` might not have the structure you expect, or might be missing the country you will eventually try to look up, etc. In these cases specific exceptions will be raised, which ideally should be handled, otherwise the program will crash.

Comment: It's somewhat common to have secrets in a `secrets.py` this way you can just `import secrets` and then do `GlobalDataLoader(secrets)`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you download the data about all countries from the API, why not save it such that getting the countries by name is easy and fast? Like a dictionary with `content['Cname'].lower()` as key?

```
class Data:
    keys = ['Cname', 'population', 'popRank', 'growthRate', 'worldPer', 'area',
            'capital', 'region', 'gdp']

    def __init__(self, api_key, project_token):
        self.url = f'https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/projects/{project_token}/last_ready_run/data'
        self.params = {"api_key": api_key}
        self.get_data()

    def get_data(self):
        r = requests.get(self.url, params=self.params)
        r.raise_for_status()
        self.data = r.json()
        self.countries = {item['Cname'].lower():
                          {key: item[key] for key in self.keys}
                          for item in self.data}

    def data_by_name(self,country):
        return self.countries(country.lower())
```

Note that I did not replicate your returning of a tuple, but just returned the dict.If you do need them in local variables, you have multiple options:

1. Just use `test["gdp"]` instead of `I`.
2. Use a `collections.namedtuple` as return value and do `test.gdp`.
3. Use `locals().update(test)` and the afterwards just `gdp`.

The first two I would prefer over the third and over your code.

Note that `A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I` are really bad names. For one, they don't follow Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which recommends `lower_case` for variables and functions. It also does note make it clear what each variable contains.

---

This

```
test = country.data_by_name("china")
list1 = []
for element in test:
    list1.append(element)
for x in list1:
    A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I = list1
```

can also be shortened to

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I = country.data_by_name("china")
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `self.data` is a bad way to cache data. There are two ways to address this.

   - Leave `get_data` roughly as is and use [`functools.cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property).
   - Take a url segment and cache it with [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) or [Beaker](https://beaker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/caching.html#decorator-api). Beaker is probably better as it allows you to have more than just an LRU cache.
2. We can use a [session object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) to remove the need for passing `params` in `get_data`. It also gives some other nice benefits, but we're not really using them here.
3. `data_by_name` doesn't belong on `Data`. This should be created and stored outside the class.

`parsehub.py`

```py
import functools

import requests


class Parsehub:
    def __init__(self, api_key, project_token):
        self._session = s = requests.Session()
        s.params.update({'api_key': api_key})
        self._project_token = project_token

    @functools.lru_cache
    def get(self, path):
        return self._session.get(
            f'https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/projects/'
            f'{self._project_token}'
            f'/{path}'
        )

    def get_data(self):
        # Code to format the countries to your desired format goes here
        return self.get('last_ready_run/data').json()
```

`__main__.py`

```py
from .settings import API_KEY, PROJECT_TOKEN
from .parsehub import Parsehub


def main():
    parse_hub = Parsehub(API_KEY, PROJECT_TOKEN)
    # The other answers have shown how to get this in the format you want.
    countries = {
        country['Cname'].lower(): country
        for country in parse_hub.get_data()
    }
    country = countries['russia']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You are missing the `json` conversion, probably in `get_data`. Otherwise, I agree, this is more maintainable.

Comment: @Graipher Aw shucks, how'd I miss that! Thank you :)